# datatype as parameter in kaitai (create generic kaitai type)

Tags: generics, kaitai-struct

let's say I have the following two types:

```
types:
  arrayf4:
    params:
      - id: size
        type: u4
    seq:
      - id: member
        type: f4
        repeat: expr
        repeat-expr: size
  arrays2:
    params:
      - id: size
        type: u4
    seq:
      - id: member
        type: s2
        repeat: expr
        repeat-expr: size
```

is it possible to implement a generic type in kaitai as follows? (this example below does not compile in kaitai Web IDE). This must be able to work not only with simple types like `s2` or `f4` but also with user-defined types.

```
types:
  generic_array:
    params:
      - id: size
        type: u4
      - id: dtype
        type: strz
    seq:
      - id: member
        type: dtype
        repeat: expr
        repeat-expr: size
```

Answer (score 1):

As understood from [this](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct/issues/135#issue-215663594) thread on GitHub, there is no generics in kaitai as of time when this answer had been posted.

I was able to find a workaround for myself - unfortunately, the workaround still requires a lot unnecessary effort to maintain. However, in my case, it still makes my kaitai code cleaner, so I am posting this solution here, in case it might be helpful for someone in a similar situation.

My generic type is defined as follows:

```
ptr:
    params:
      - id: dtype
        type: str
    seq:
      - id: offset
        type: u4
    instances:
      data:
        pos: offset
        type:
          switch-on: dtype
          cases:
            '"material"': material
            '"node"': node
            '"animation"': animation
            _: unknown_type
```

In code this type is used as follows:

```
seq:
  - id: material
    type: ptr('material')
```

*Pros.*

1. The code using the `ptr` type becomes much cleaner. I have a lot of pointers of this type in the binary format I am parsing, so this has made my code immediately a ton more readable.
2. The generated code (`python`, in my case) is truly generic. You always get the same `Ptr` class for your object, and the `data` inside may be of any type defined, in my case `material`, `node`, or `animation`, so at the end it has exactly the effect I was aiming for.

*Cons.*

1. Obviously, you have to manually add types which are accepted by this generic type - in the `switch-on` clause, otherwise by default it will be set to an `unknown` type which is simply defined as an empty dummy which does not read any bytes. If you have several generic types, this scales respectively. I initially thought about writing a pre-processing routine but in my case it is easier to maintain this manually.
2. Secondly, nested generic types won't work. For example, `ptr('other_generic(some_type)')`, of course, won't work.